# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.gora.hbase.store.HBaseStore

Tags: hbase, nutch

I try to run Nutch 2.0 with HBase as a storage backend for Gora.
I following this Tutorial: `http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/Nutch2Tutorial` and got java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError; this tutorial also covers this error by "copy the lib over from your installed HBase dir into the build lib dir" but I don't know which exactly hbase TEST jar need to copy.
If have anyone success run Nutch 2.0 with HBase, please tell me which jar file I need to copy.
Thanks you very much.
(Sorry about my English writing skill)

Answer (score 1):

It is not the NoClassDefFoundError from the tutorial.
What you miss is `gora-hbase-0.2.1.jar`.
Did you forget to configure gora-hbase dependency in ivy?

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by wrong build configuration. To fix this just open `/ivy/ivy.xml` and uncomment these lines:

```
<dependency org="org.apache.gora" name="gora-core" rev="0.4" conf="*->default"/>
<dependency org="org.apache.gora" name="gora-hbase" rev="0.4" conf="*->default" />
```

And rebuild your nutch with:

```
ant clean
ant runtime
```

If it doesn't help then Nutch 2 tutorial says:

> It's possible to encounter the following exception:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/hadoop/hbase/HBaseConfiguration; this is caused by the fact
>   that sometimes the hbase TEST jar is deployed in the lib dir. To
>   resolve this just copy the lib over from your installed HBase dir into
>   the build lib dir. (This issue is currently in progress).